# ceil works without including <cmath> in visual c++ 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++-2010

I just wrote a simple C++ program in Visual Studio 2010 and I use `ceil` function. But I forgot to include the `<cmath>` and only included the `<iostream>`. Surprisingly my code compiled successfully and ran without any error. I read a C++ book and it clearly says that to use `ceil` function you must include `<cmath>` or `<math.h>`. Why this happens? Can anyone explain me? Thanks!

Comment: iostream includes istream includes ostream includes ios includes xlocnum includes cmath includes math.h.  num_get::do_get() uses ldexp().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header is indirectly included from some other (indirectly) included header.

To find out which one, enable 'keep preprocessed source' (`/P`) from the project options and inspect the resulting (*.i) file

**Update** Just found out that VS2010 has renamed the related option:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking, implementations are allowed to automatically include any header in the system headers. But this is implementation defined.

In some cases, `<cmath>` is already included, in other cases, it isn't - same applies to all the other standard headers.

This issue came up on this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7632926/is-this-a-c-program-or-c-program-how-to-decide

That aside, it's possible that it could be indirectly included by other includes.